# Let $ R = \mathbb{ F }_2[x]/(x^2) $. Determine all the ideals in $ R $.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> (3) Let $ R = \mathbb{ F }_2[x]/(x^2) $. Determine all the ideals in $ R $.
>
> $$ R := \frac{ \mathbb{ F }_2[x] }{ (x^2) },$$
>
> the quotient of the polynomial ring $ \mathbb{ F }_2[x] $ (read "f two $ x $") over $ \mathbb{ F }_2 $ (i.e., polynomials whose coefficients belong the field of two elements, $ \mathbb{ F }_2 $, by the principal ideal ($ x^2 $).

Comment: Ideals in $R$ are in $1$-$1$ correspondence with ideals in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ containing $(x^2)$.

Comment: What issues are you having finding a solution?

Comment: $\mathbb{F}_2 / (x^2)$ only has four elements. Apart from the trivial ideal and the full ring, all the other subgroups (and hence subrings) must have two elements, each including $0$. You just need to check which of these $3$ subgroups are ideals.

Answer (score 1):

$R=\{0,1,x,x+1\}$.

Thus $(0),(1)=R, (x)$ and $(x+1)$ are the only candidates. (Of course,  $(x,x+1)=R$).

That leaves two possible nontrivial ideals: $(x)$ and $(x+1)$.  But, $x\cdot (x+1)=x^2+x=x$.  So $(x+1)=R$.

That leaves only one ideal:  $(x)$.

Alternatively, $(x)$ is the only (nontrivial)  ideal in $\mathbb F_2[x]$ containing $(x^2)$.